# How do I run a random method from a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, how can I randomly use one of the four functions (within the class) listed below?

```
import random

class Calculate():
    def HI_1(x, y):
        return x + y
    def HI_2(x, y):
        return x - y
    def HI_3(x, y):
        return x * y
    def HI_4(x, y):
        return x/y


a = random.randint(1, 4)
b = 'HI_' + str(a)

p = Calculate.b(15, 7)
print(p)
```

My attempt to do so came with an error. Why did I get this error, and how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr), in addition your methods must be declared as [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod):

```
import random

class Calculate():
    @staticmethod
    def HI_1(x, y):
        return x + y

    @staticmethod
    def HI_2(x, y):
        return x - y

    @staticmethod
    def HI_3(x, y):
        return x * y

    @staticmethod
    def HI_4(x, y):
        return x/y


a = random.randint(1, 4)
b = 'HI_' + str(a)
p = getattr(Calculate, b)(15, 7)
print(b, p)
```

Answer (score 1):

b is still a string. You need to evaluate it into an expression:

```
a = random.randint(1, 4)
b = 'HI_' + str(a)
func = eval("Calculate.{}".format(b))
func(15, 7)
```

Note you shouldn't be using `eval()` on any string that is a user input because it can lead to security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

First, your methods should either be static or have `self` as first argument. Once that is fixed, you could use `random.choice` instead to choose the method out of a list. This has the advantage of not depending on the methods' names.

```
import random

class Calculate:
    @staticmethod
    def add(x, y):
        return x + y

    @staticmethod
    def sub(x, y):
        return x - y

    @staticmethod
    def mult(x, y):
        return x * y

    @staticmethod
    def div(x, y):
        return x/y

    @classmethod
    def random_op(cls, x, y):
        return random.choice([
            cls.add,
            cls.sub,
            cls.mult,
            cls.div
        ])(x, y)
```